# Font identification, again

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-face

[image]

Can anyone identify this font in the image?

It's also here :

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_34886/

Comment: This is a wonderful tool
http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, well... found it myself..too late :P

It's Lobster!

http://www.impallari.com/lobster

http://www.dafont.com/lobster.font?text=Hi+there

Comment: Now forget you have ever seen this awesome typeface! Do not use it! :P :)

Comment: If you ever need someone to listen while you talk to yoursef, we're here for you, buddy.

Comment: Just for future reference, if you ever get stuck again:

http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

It's an epic tool.

Comment: tried it on several characters but its kind of tricky with scripty fonts cause it doesnt identify the letters individually , it picks up groups like , the, and you have only one box to fill in to say what letter is that... so sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.identifont.com/ is another tool where you answer questions about the font's characteristics rather than relying on OCR.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great app called WhatTheFont for the iPhone. You snap a picture of a font, validate the character recognition got the right letters, and it will identify the font.

Comment: great... now I just need an iPhone :)
Question EDIT:

Comment: Anybody here wants to give me an iPhone so I can identify fonts from now on and stop asking on stackexchange about it ? :P :)